# how to use same identifier for different directory paths in EJS with different static assets folder in Nodejs web app

Tags: node.js, static, ejs, bundle, fastify

#### Issue

this is my ejs

```
<head>
   
     <%- include('../../public/components/headercontent.html'); %>
     
</head>
```

and below is my app/server.js file configuration

```
fastify.register(require("point-of-view"), {
  engine: {
    ejs: require("ejs"),
  },
  root: path.join(__dirname, "../views"),
});


fastify.register(require("fastify-static"), {
  root: path.join(__dirname, "../") + "/public/",
});
```

so the above works as expected my problem statement is below
i have two static assets folder

- public
- public-release

what is expected scenario is

I want to use same public name but path can be different
something like
case scenario 1

```
fastify.register(require("fastify-static"), {
  root: path.join(__dirname, "../") + "/**public-release**/",
  nameused:'public'
});
```

case scenario 2

```
fastify.register(require("fastify-static"), {
  root: path.join(__dirname, "../") + "/**public**/",
  nameused:'public'
});
```

is there a way I can achieve this ?

**Objective :**

1.i want to switch dynamically my js and css for home grown release /bundling system
and without touching my existing codebase of linking them

2.so the idea here is to just the
update the point where static assests are served and change them through custom yarn or npm run scripts

3. **for eg:- when i pass say dev the static assets should serve from 'public ' folder with 'public' as alias**

   **and when i pass say prod the static assets should serve from 'public-release' folder with 'public' as alias**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So , there is middle ground approach which I implemented
for my boilerplate

[Github Repo: Node.js Postgresql fastify](https://github.com/matt212/Nodejs_Postgresql_VanillaJS_Fastify)

TLDR;

[image: Node.js web APP Release Mechanism pt-1]

[image: Node.js web APP Release Mechanism pt-2]

[image: How to Release Node.js Web APP]